# for loop on huge number

Tags: php, for-loop, numbers

PHP

```
$SCode=$_POST['SCode'];
$ECode=$_POST['ECode'];

for($p=$SCode;$p<$ECode;$p++)
{
    $dbResult= $dbHandle->query("
    SELECT Code
    FROM Mashaghel 
    Where Code=" . $p . "");
    if(!isset($Mashaghel[0]["Code"]) || empty($Mashaghel[0]["Code"]))
    {
        $errorCode.=$p."،";
    }
}
echo $errorCode."does not existed!";
```

i run this with

```
$_POST['SCode']='010100100101002084';
$_POST['ECode']='010100100101002087';
```

but this does not worked and say error `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded` While The difference between `010100100101002084` and `010100100101002087` only 3.

why for loop do infinite!?

please help me

Comment: Shouldn't `$Mashaghel` be `$dbResult`?

Comment: You realise that values like `010100100101002084` are too large to be represented as 32-bit signed integers (guessing that you're running 32-bit PHP); plus you lose leading zeroes when casting them to numbers

Comment: @MarkBaker Won't it switch to floating point for numbers too large for integers?

Comment: Why don't you just use `WHERE Code BETWEEN $SCode AND $ECode` and loop through results?

Comment: Yes, it will do that switch, but then you're possibly getting into the realms of float inaccuracy

Comment: @Anthony - which will be a single query, and a lot less overhead on the system... a far better approach than an individual query every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for($p=0;$p<bcsub($ECode,$SCode);$p++)
    {
        $dbResult= $dbHandle->query("SELECT Code FROM Mashaghel
Where Code=" . bcadd($SCode,$p) . "");
        if(!isset($Mashaghel[0]["Code"]) || empty($Mashaghel[0]["Code"]))
        {
            $errorCode.=bcadd($SCode,$p)."،";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script is executing so long might be the query inside your loop. You could try to add 'LIMIT 1' to your query so it only processes one row or change 1 to the number of rows you need to process.
If you still want to make your script be able to execute longer here's more info about it. By default, PHP terminates the script after 60 seconds to prevent scripts from hanging. There is a value in php.ini defining maximum time PHP script can run - it's called `max_execution_time`. You can also change this value for particular script by `running set_time_limit()` function ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)).

Comment: Why would 3 simple SQL queries take more than a minute? See my comments on @stony's answer.

Comment: Edited my answer. Maybe the query only needs to process one row.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 for($p=$SCode;$p<$ECode;$p++)
```

to

```
for($p=0; $p < ($ECode - $SCode - 1); $p++)
```

And references to `$p` inside the loop to `$p+$SCode`

Comment: echo (string)$p+$SCode  return `1.0100100101002E+16` how get correct format mean 010100100101002086

Comment: It should not work.$ECode - $SCode will produce 4 but it should be 3

Comment: Check more.The difference is 3 but it does not produce 3.It produce 4

Comment: @ShaifulIslam rights,`$p+$SCode` return wrong value, this return all time 1.0100100101002E+16

Answer (score 0):

break the limit of for into two numbers . for example think that your for loop limit number is 1000 break it to 100,10 make 2 nested for loops .

and for some numbers which are not dividable you can do some for loops one after another for example think that your number is 11
do it 5+6 like you have 2 for loops run exactly after each other with exact code in loop.
also you can test while loop.

after all I don't think it's a solution it is just a way you can solve your problem temporary.